# Url Rewrite doesn't work on apache server godaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I host my website on a godaddy webserver and i try to use htaccess file to rewrite some urls but it doesn't work. Help would be very appreciated.

Basically I would like to replace an url like:

`/photographers/photographer.php?id=1&name=john-doe`

in:

`/photographer/john-doe`

Obviously I would like also my server to redirect internally in the opposite way.

I tried the following code in my .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^photographer/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ photographers/photographer.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without ID.

Add id in the url:

```
/photographer/john-doe/1
```

And that .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^photographer/([A-Za-z-]+)/(\d+)/?$ photographers/photographer.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it's still not working. There is something else the server doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Query String Append flag (QSA)

```htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^photographer/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ photographers/photographer.php?id=$2&name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

You could also try removing the `RewriteBase` line to see if that helps too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. only one line :)

```
RewriteRule ^(photographer)/(.*)$ /photographers/photographer.php?id=1&name=$2 [L]
```